# mysqldump not executing through PHP

Tags: php, linux, exec, mysql

I am using php exec function to try to backup a database, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I have tried different variations:

```
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpwd = "somepass";
$dbhost = "localhost";
$db = "somedb";
$dir = "/var/www/backup/";
$filename = $db.".sql";

exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump -u '.$dbuser.' -p'.$dbpwd.' -h '.$dbhost.' '.$db.' > '.$dir.$filename);
```

This works running through SSH logged in as root.  The -p wouldn't seem to work with a space, so when I took that away it worked through SSH. When I run whoami from the exec in PHP I get apache.  Would that be the issue?  If so, how would I fix that?

This is a linux box.  I don't get any errors in the PHP script (set display_errors at top to be sure) and the exec command echos nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Print out the entire command from php and run it yourself as the apache or php user -- not root unless you have it configured like this.

Comment: I have printed out the command and run it, but only through root.  The files are owned and part of the group root.  The db user and password I am using the root login details.  I am not sure how to login as apache as I have not setup any for that.

Comment: I use `sudo -u apache /usr/bin/mysqldump ...` where apache is the user  you want to run it as

Comment: You echoed the command generated from php, prepended it with `sudo -u apache` and it ran fine? You didn't build the command yourself or change anything from how PHP generated it?

Comment: Use passthru() instead of exec() while testing as it will output the raw output from the command. It might give you a useful error.

Comment: Yep. Would perhaps the directory storing be an issue or would it fail in both cases?

Comment: you run into the same issue when executing git pull via `exec(git pull -u origin master)` it has to do with permissions. @MikeB has it right.

Comment: Fixed.  Just need to set the permissions to 777 on the directory where I am storing the file.

Comment: @fanfavorite How could the command function without proper permissions?

Comment: The command worked because I was SSHed into root, which owned the folder where it was storing, but php was running the command as apache.  So I assume the sudo -u apache was running as apache for the mysqldump, but the actual file to store to was still allowing since I was in as root.  I could be wrong, but it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works logged in as root and not as another user and you are sure there is nothing different in the command (exactly the same user, pass, etc) the most likely problem is permissions.  In this case it is the directory where the file is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

A ugly solution: create a mysql user that can only read stuff (not update, drop,etc.. powers) and need no password and is limited to connect from localhost. So you don't need the -p param.